# Has mining in Ultima online changed?

Tags: ultima-online

In Ultima online, do you still have to just pick a spot and use a pickaxe/shovel and hope to get the ore your looking for or has it changed so you know where to mine and for what? I like to have a mining/blacksmith with his own shop but getting the ore and other materials was a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you're playing 'old-school' UO?

As far as I can remember *(NOSTALGIA OVERLOAD)* ore spawn is fixed.  If you hit upon the good stuff, you should mark a rune on the spot because it will certainly spawn there again.  It is still a simple matter of double clicking the shovel (in backpack) or pickaxe (in hand) and targeting location.

But the amount yielded varies alot (large min-max amount depending on your mining skill - but also the type of ore you dig).  Very rare deposits are easily overlooked because it may yield just iron.

There are many tips to be had.  Oh this game is amazing I've just remembered stuff.

Answer (score 0):

ore spawn in original UO has changed since 2007. Ore spots aren't static anymore, they reset every now and then.